# How to apply a middle mouse button for hand tool in the Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

I have the latest Sketch and I want to use *Hand Tool* with my middle mouse button instead of Spacebar. I know how to make new hotkeys for Sketch in the keyboard settings, but I can't apply Hand Tool for MMB.
Thank you.

Comment: As shortcuts for Sketch are set using Apple's system preferences, I would suggest to move this to SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

**Steermouse** from http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/
should allow you to remap the middle button to space or anything else.
You can use it for free for 30 days to see if it works for you.

This video shows how it works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nUHNbmwAh8

Also, you could buy a programmable mouse like what is used for gaming and set the shortcuts on that. Make sure the bundled software is apple compatible though.

That will benefit you in any graphic design programs that have a lot of hotkeys.